# Access HTTP service running in GKE from Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an HTTP service running on a Google Container Engine cluster (behind a kubernetes service).

My goal is to access that service from a Dataflow job running on the same GCP project using a fixed name (in the same way services can be reached from inside GKE using DNS). Any idea?

---

- Most solutions I have read on stackoverflow relies on having kube-proxy installed on the machines trying to reach the service. As far as I know, it is not possible to reliably set up that service on every worker instance created by Dataflow.
- One option is to create an external balancer and create an A record in the public DNS. Although it works, I would rather not have an entry in my public DNS records pointing to that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dataflow job running on GCP will not be part of the Google Container Engine cluster, so it will not have access to the internal cluster DNS by default.

Try [setting](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) up a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/load-balancer) for the service that you want to expose which knows how to route the "external" traffic to it. This will allow you to connect to the IP address directly from a Dataflow job executing on GCP.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:
this is now supported on GKE** (now known as Kubernetes Engine): https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing

I have implemented this in a pretty smooth way IMHO. I will try to walk through briefly how it works:

- Remember that when you create a container cluster (or nodepool), it will consist of a set of GCE instances in an instance group that is a part of the default network. NB: add a specific GCE network tag(s) so that you can add only those instances to a firewall rule later for letting load balancer check instance health.
- This instance group is just a regular instance group.
- Now, remember that kubernetes has something called `NodePort`, which will expose the service at this port on all nodes, i.e all GCE instances in your cluster. This is what we want!
- Now that we know that we have a set of GCE instances in an instance group we can then add this instance group to an *internal* load balancer in your default network without it needing to know anything about kubernetes internals or DNS.
- The Guide which you can follow, skipping many of the initial steps is here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/
- Remember that this works for regions, so dataflow and everything else must be in the same region.

See this spec for the service:

```
kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: name
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
    name: name
    app: app
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - name: health
    protocol: TCP
   enter code here port: 8081
    nodePort: 30081
  - name: api
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    nodePort: 30080
  type: NodePort
```

This is the code for setting up the load balancer with health checks, forwarding rules and firewall that it needs to work:

```
_region=<THE_REGION>
_instance_group=<THE_NODE_POOL_INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME>
#Can be different for your case
_healtcheck_path=/liveness
_healtcheck_port=30081
_healtcheck_name=<THE_HEALTCHECK_NAME>
_port=30080
_tags=<TAGS>
_loadbalancer_name=internal-loadbalancer-$_region
_loadbalancer_ip=10.240.0.200

gcloud compute health-checks create http $_healtcheck_name \
  --port $_healtcheck_port \
  --request-path $_healtcheck_path

gcloud compute backend-services create $_loadbalancer_name \
  --load-balancing-scheme internal \
  --region $_region \
  --health-checks $_healtcheck_name

gcloud compute backend-services add-backend $_loadbalancer_name \
  --instance-group $_instance_group \
  --instance-group-zone $_region-a \
  --region $_region

gcloud compute forwarding-rules create $_loadbalancer_name-forwarding-rule \
  --load-balancing-scheme internal \
  --ports $_port \
  --region $_region \
  --backend-service $_loadbalancer_name \
  --address $_loadbalancer_ip
#Allow google cloud to healthcheck your instance
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-$_healtcheck_name \
  --source-ranges 130.211.0.0/22,35.191.0.0/16 \
  --target-tags $_tags \
  --allow tcp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info.

Also, hope this helps others: You can run the service as a LoadBalancer type and add the "internal" annotation tag. Redeploy the service and GKE should handle the setup for you. Takes about 2 min and 5 LOC.

Answer (score 2):

Lukasz's answer is probably the most straightforward way to expose your service to dataflow. But, if you really don't want a public IP and DNS record, you can use a GCE route to deliver traffic to your cluster's private IP range (something like option 1 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664060/how-to-call-a-service-exposed-by-a-kubernetes-cluster-from-another-kubernetes-cl/31665248#31665248)).

This would let you hit your service's stable IP. I'm not sure how to get Kubernetes' internal DNS to resolve from Dataflow.

Comment: This works with dataflow? Dataflow runs inside of VPCs and will work with routes? Looks like you need to create the dataflow job with the --network arg to accomplish this?