# How to access services in K8s from the internal non-K8s network?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**Question**: How can I provide reliable access from (non-K8s) services running in an GCE network to other services running inside Kubernetes?

**Background**: We are running a **hosted K8s** setup in the **Google Cloud Platform**. Most services are **12factor apps** and **run** just **fine** within K8s. Some **backing stores** (databases) are run **outside of K8s**. Accessing them is easy by using headless services with manually defined endpoints to fixed internal IPs. Those services usually do not need to "talk back" to the services in K8s.

But **some services** running in the internal GCE network (but **outside of K8s**) need to **access services running within K8s**. We can expose the K8s services using `spec.type: NodePort` and talk to this port on any of the K8s Nodes IPs. But how can we automatically find the right NodePort and a valid Worker Node IP? Or maybe there is even a better way to solve this issue.

This setup is probably not a typical use-case for a K8s deployment, but we'd like to go this way until PetSets and Persistent Storage in K8s have matured enough.

As we are talking about internal services I'd like to avoid using an external loadbalancer in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can make cluster service IPs meaningful outside of the cluster (but inside the private network) either by creating a "bastion route" or by running kube-proxy on the machine you are connecting from (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664060/how-to-call-a-service-exposed-by-a-kubernetes-cluster-from-another-kubernetes-cl/31665248#31665248)).

I think you could also point your resolv.conf at the cluster's DNS service to be able to resolve service DNS names. This could get tricky if you have multiple clusters though.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use an Ingress Controller. Ingress Controllers are designed to provide access from outside a Kubernetes cluster to services running inside the cluster. An Ingress Controller runs as a pod within the cluster and will route requests from outside the cluster to the correct services inside the cluster, based on the configured rules. This provides a secure and reliable way for non-Kubernetes services running in a GCE network to access services running in Kubernetes.