# Kubernetes - Discover and access another cluster service like self-hosted

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, microservices, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

### What I want

- ClusterA have PodA
- ClusterB have ServiceB select PodB in `namespace:default`
- In GKE(Google Kubernetes Engine)

PodA in ClusterA can access ServiceB in clusterB like `api.default.svc.cluster.clusterB`.

### Solutions I tried

- GKE Internal Load Balancer: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing

  - It works. But I need to create a lot of ILB for each one of services.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665248/3854890

  - I don't think manually configure kube-proxy is a good choice since I'm using preemptible VMs.
- Kubefed: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed

  - I didn't dig it too deep. It's like manipulate multiple cluster and expose them. And what I what it communicates internally.
- Maesh https://containo.us/maesh/

  - Didn't see cross cluster configurations.
- Istio https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/

  - A little complicated to me. Not sure it suit to this scenario.

---

Any solutions or ideas are appreciated! A example will be better.

Comment: are these two kubernetes cluster in same network / flat network,
you want to  access it with serviceB.default.svc.cluster.local ?

Comment: I am not sure if what you are trying is easily achievable. Please tell is there any reason that you are trying to use 2 clusters? Have you thought about using single cluster with additional node pool? You could spawn a specific workload only on it by using `nodeSelector`. Here is the link if you are interested: [Kubernetes.io: Create a pod that gets scheduled to your chosen node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/#create-a-pod-that-gets-scheduled-to-your-chosen-node)

Comment: @NadeemHussain In same GCP project and same region for now. But i will also need to access other cluster outside GCP. `serviceB.default.svc.cluster.local ` is ok. With a cluster name suffix will be better.

Comment: @DawidKruk Cross region. Cross cloud platform. So more node pool don't work to me.

Comment: if i understand clear your end goal is to access svc  from one cluster to another and both 
these clusters can be on different network ,  if so , why don't you expose these svc via internal loadbalancer nginx ingress. , that way you dont have to create multiple load balancers too , just  ingress crd  will work for each svc

Comment: @NadeemHussain My goal is communicate between two cluster and "discover" services. So ingress didn't help too much. I guess I need expose some kind of dns service to VPC.

Comment: If the clusters were in the same cloud provider you could try to use `VPC Network Peering`: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering. This solution has a caveat that you would be able to communicate only through ip addresses, not service names. Also, please take a look here: [Istio.io: Install: Multisluster: Shared](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared/) - it's a guide for Istio deployment with multiple clusters. The guide also mentions service discovery between clusters. Please let me know if the solution with Istio would be satisfactory.

Comment: @RammusXu is using the mentioned DNS pattern required? An alternative would be to create a public DNS Zone and let it be managed by [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns). This way you can give services annotations which are picked up by external-dns, which will then create DNS records in the managed zone containing the private IPs (so it's only partly public). The next part of the solution would be to use (cross-region) network peering, so that the private IP is routable between clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found three solutions for this. For multi-cluster kubernetes architecture.

- Linkerd: https://linkerd.io/2/features/multicluster/index.html
- Consule: https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/kubernetes/mesh-gateways
- Istio: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared/

I chose Linkerd. Pretty easy to setup, good latency and good documents.

I also wrote an article in Chinese if someone interested.
https://rammusxu.github.io/2020/07/28/Linkerd-Multi-Kubernetes-Cluster-Feature-Overview/